# NHibernate Query across multiple tables

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql, icriteria

I am using NHibernate, and am trying to figure out how to write a query, that searchs all the names of my entities,
and lists the results. As a simple example, I have the following objects;

```
public class Cat {
public string name {get; set;}
}

public class Dog {
    public string name {get; set;}
}

public class Owner {
    public string firstname {get; set;}
    public string lastname {get; set;}
}
```

Eventaully I want to create a query , say for example,  which and returns all the pet owners with an name containing "ted", OR pets with a name containing "ted".

Here is an example of the SQL I want to execute:

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.*, c.*, o.* FROM owners AS o
INNER JOIN dogs AS d ON o.id = d.ownerId 
INNER JOIN cats AS c ON o.id = c.ownerId
WHERE o.lastname like '%ted%' 
OR o.firstname like '%ted%' 
OR c.name like '%ted%' 
OR d.name like '%ted%'
```

When I do it using Criteria like this:

```
    var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Owner>()
        .Add(
        Restrictions.Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.Like("FirstName", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
            .Add(Restrictions.Like("LastName", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
        )
        .CreateCriteria("Dog").Add(Restrictions.Like("Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
        .CreateCriteria("Cat").Add(Restrictions.Like("Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere));
        return criteria.List<Owner>();
```

The following query is generated:

```
   SELECT TOP 10 d.*, c.*, o.* FROM owners AS o
   INNER JOIN dogs AS d ON o.id = d.ownerId 
   INNER JOIN cats AS c ON o.id = c.ownerId 
   WHERE o.lastname like '%ted%' 
   OR o.firstname like '%ted%' 
   AND d.name like '%ted%'
   AND c.name like '%ted%'
```

How can I adjust my query so that the .CreateCriteria("Dog") and  .CreateCriteria("Cat") generate an OR instead of the AND?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it might work.

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Owner>()
            .CreateAlias("Dog", "d")
            .CreateAlias("Cat", "c")
            .Add(
            Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Restrictions.Like("FirstName", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .Add(Restrictions.Like("LastName", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .Add(Restrictions.Like("c.Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .Add(Restrictions.Like("d.Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
            );
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do it. I found a post here: http://mattthr.blogspot.com/2010/02/quey-across-join-in-nhibernate.html and was going to try that

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the two criteria using Expression.Or(criteria1, criteria2)

More here: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/04/21/creating-a-nested-or-statement-with-nhibernate-using-the-criteria-convention.aspx

Hmm I think it would look like this (borrowed a bit from BuggyDigger's code)

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Owner>()
    .CreateAlias("Dog", "d")
    .CreateAlias("Cat", "c")
    .Add(Expression.Or(Expression.Like("c.Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere)
            , Expression.Like("d.Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
        );
```

But I didn't notice that you wanted to OR everything.  In that case adding these criteria to the disjunction, as BuggyDigger showed, is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks fo rthe reply Alex, could you provide an example. I tried what you did, but I get "can not convert ICriteria to Icriterion"

Comment: Clarified in my post, but since I read the question wrong it may not matter ;)